# How to make the axes start from zero in package fitdistrplus in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, axes, fitdistrplus

I use function `fitdist` in package `fitdistrplus` to get the best distribution fitted to my data and draw the `ppcomp` figure , I use the example codes of `?fitdistrplus` to replace my data and codes.

```
data(groundbeef)
serving <- groundbeef$serving
fitW <- fitdist(serving, "weibull")
fitg <- fitdist(serving, "gamma")
fitln <- fitdist(serving, "lnorm")
ppcomp(list(fitW, fitg, fitln), legendtext=c("Weibull", "gamma", "lognormal"))
```

[image: ppcomp]

So far so good! But look at the left bottom of the pic, there is some space, or the axes does not start from zero!

So I googled and find two methods:
One method in the base plot, `xaxs` and `yaxs` are used.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- runif(100, min=0, max=100)
y <- runif(100, min=0, max=100)
plot(x,y,xaxs="i",yaxs="i",xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(0,100))
```

[image: base plot]

Another method in the `ggplot2`, `expand=c(0,0)` is used.

```
df <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0))
```

[image: expand]

So I try to use these two methods to draw the `ppcomp` figure,

```
ppcomp(list(fitW, fitg, fitln), legendtext=c("Weibull", "gamma", "lognormal"),xaxs="i",yaxs="i")
```

but error occurs:

```
Error in legend(x = xlegend, y = ylegend, bty = "n", legend = legendtext,  : 
  unused arguments (xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
```

So, what should I do to complete the goal without the error, or what is the right codes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that the `...` argument in `ppcomp` (which accepts the extra arguments) is given to both `plot` and `legend` and `legend` does not know what to do with `xaxs`.

Options are:

1) Run `ppcomp` with `xaxs`, which will make the plot and then add the `legend` separately.

2) Use `fix(ppcomp)` to delete the `...` from the `legend` commands.

3) Recode `ppcomp` to use `ggplot` and set the options as you please.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, I tried Options 2, and it works. But as to options 1, it does not work. And about Options 3, I am not good at coding, so I do not have a try.